# How to include mpi.h in CLion on Windows machine

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, mpi, clion

It says cannot find `mpi.h` and after I run the code following error is shown:

`fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory`.

I am using `TDM-GCC` (`MinGW` enviroment).

So far I downloaded and installed [MS-MPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb524831.aspx).

Now I am trying to figure out **how to include** `mpi.h` **successfully in** `CLion`.

Here is the code snippet (actually not relevant ATM):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h> // THIS IS THE PROBLEM

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  const int tag = 42;           /* Message tag */
  int   id, ntasks, source_id, err, i;
  MPI_Status status;
  char msg[80];                /* Message array */

// irrelevant code
// irrelevant code
}
```

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt` file (just default):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(mpi_test_clion)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES mpi_hello.cpp)
add_executable(mpi_test_clion ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: Open MPI is no longer supported on Windows. MS-MPI is a good choice though it does not implement the entire MPI specification, mostly some parts that you are probably not going to use anyway. You should add the path to `mpi.h` to the list of include directories and the path to `libmpi.lib` to the list of library paths. No idea how to do this in CLion though. Perhaps @JonathanDursi could weigh in ;)

Comment: I have tried various methods from around the internet and SO, nothing works and I cannot figure it out. Every tutorial is for Linux or OS X and its different on those systems.

Comment: Setting the include and library paths for the project is not MPI-specific. Look in the documentation of CLion.

Comment: I did my friend, CLion documentation for including external libraries and .h files is very poorly written, also every example I found on the internet is either for Linux or for OS X or is not sufficient

Comment: Just out of the blue. Can you see the MPI in the path. [This](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/windowshpc/2015/02/02/how-to-compile-and-run-a-simple-ms-mpi-program/) article was written as the env variable tutorial for VS, but I think it can be applied in your case, and I think you can use it with [ENV](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/ENV.html) in your CMake file